# Search list (Find an item) SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2016, search-results, enterprise-search

Tell me if there is any rule in the Search that can be used when finding all elements that match the value expression, i.e. if you wrote the word "Test", then the list item "Test1", "Test2" would also be shown?

[image]

Only "*Test*", not "**Test1**" and "**Test2**"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter **Test*** in the “Find an item" search box to get all items that contain Test.

[image]

[image]